# KnockoutJS IE8 performance issues and memory leaks

Tags: performance, internet-explorer-8, knockout.js, memory-leaks

We build complex enterprise application using KnockoutJS and faced poor performance especially in IE8. Application might take more than 1GB of RAM and never frees memory. During investigation we discovered that KnockoutJS keeps references to the DOM nodes and never deletes it. This can be reproduced using IESieve against any public KnockoutJS example, just watch DOM utilization while playing with example which adds and deletes DOM nodes.

Have anyone faced this problem and has any ideas of how to work this out?

Comment: I have not encountered this problem. Perhaps there is an issue with your application.

Comment: lucky you, however there are different people complaining too @ knockoutjs forum. Do you do anything special to treat IE8?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Knockoutjs but I am familiar with IE-based development. If Knockoutjs is using javascript closures referencing the DOM, these may lead to dangling references resulting in poor performance and memory leaks. In order to fix these you'd most likely need to modify the javascript library.

Comment: Hi Anthill, you're right, that's the problem. We are looking for somebody who probably did that :)

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Are you applying bindings more than once?

Comment: I had issues with IE8 performance, and it led me to discover that my knockout code -- in particular, some custom binding handlers -- was inefficient. Other browsers had the same issues, but they weren't noticeable, because the other browsers' JS engines' speed made up for the poor code.

Comment: Please update on how the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

We had faced similar issues with knockout JS on IE 8. One of the problem areas was having an observable array (with 500+ elements) and building a UI (imagine a table like or list like structure) with all of those. 
The only work around that worked for us was to change the view model so that it contains only very few items that could fit on the screen. Also, we had to add handlers for scroll events so that the observable array would keep getting refreshed. And (not too proud of this), we had to add an empty div at the top of the displayed records to give an illusion of the view having scrolled.

Comment: Could you share some code on the same? We too are looking something similar.

Comment: Cannot give any code but the high level logic was like this. Held all the records in a javascript array, say masterData. Based on the UI identified the number of records displayed on the page at a time, say pageSize. Now on the first load, from the masterData add only pageSize number of records to the VMs observable array. Also calculated what would be the total rendered page size for the total number of records. Now to the scrolling part. More below.

Comment: Added a scroll handler for the page, in which based on the scroll position and the total height of the web page, calculate the current index. Now empty out the VM and add from teh master data, records starting from current index to current index + pageSize. Add an empty div of size recordsize*current index before the first rendered element to give the illusion of a proper scroll. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any samples available on loading large data like ondemand kind of loading. If we fetch and store all the records in ajavascript array, it will impact the memory on the client side. How do we handle such situations.

Answer (score 1):

Probably to do with event bindings not being released when their DOM elements get deleted. If it's something thats happening under the hood with knockout, you will have to patch and submit a pull request.

I've had this kind of thing happen a lot with backbonejs too. JavascriptMVC is a bit better for cleaning up after itself.

Comment: What you have mentioned here is true. The issue is the event bindings and also some of the dom references not being released properly.